# Length of nested array lua

Tags: multidimensional-array, lua, lua-table

I am having trouble figuring out how to get the length of a matrix within a matrix within a matrix (nested depth of 3). So what the code is doing in short is... looks to see if the publisher is already in the array, then it either adds a new column in the array with a new publisher and the corresponding system, or adds the new system to the existing array publisher

`output[k][1]` is the publisher array
`output[k][2][l]` is the system

where the first [] is the amount of different publishers
and the second [] is the amount of different systems within the same publisher

So how would I find out what the length of the third deep array is?

```
function reviewPubCount()
    local output = {}
    local k = 0
    for i = 1, #keys do
        if string.find(tostring(keys[i]), '_') then
            key = Split(tostring(keys[i]), '_')
            for j = 1, #reviewer_code do
                if key[1] == reviewer_code[j] and key[1] ~= '' then
                    k = k + 1
                    output[k] = {}
                   -- output[k] = reviewer_code[j]
                    for l = 1, k do
                        if output[l][1] == reviewer_code[j] then
                            ltable = output[l][2]
                            temp = table.getn(ltable)
                            output[l][2][temp+1] = key[2]
                        else
                            output[k][1] = reviewer_code[j]
                            output[k][2][1] = key[2]
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
    return output
end
```

The code has been fixed here for future reference: http://codepad.org/3di3BOD2#output

Comment: Where are `ltable` and `temp` declared? As they appear in your code now it seems they are global variables. Did you forget to add a `local` keyword in front of them or in your design they are really globals?

Comment: @user2872731 The length of *which one* of the tables in the 3rd level?

Comment: I would really recommend using descriptive strings instead of magic numbers. Having a field called `output[k].publisher` and a subtable `output[k].reviewer_codes` would make your code so much cleaner and your life easier.

Comment: http://codepad.org/3di3BOD2 this is the code it semi works it stores the values correctly but the if statments are not working so it is using more resources then needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to replace `table.getn(t)` with `#t` (it's deprecated in Lua 5.1 and removed in Lua 5.2); instead of this:

```
ltable = output[l][2]
temp = table.getn(ltable)
output[l][2][temp+1] = key[2]
```

try this:

```
output[l][2][#output[l][2]+1] = key[2]
```

or this:

```
table.insert(output[l][2], key[2])
```